# Как поднять табличку на самый верх

Tags: php, html, css

Вот ссылка http://mafiag.0fees.us/user.php

Я понимаю что использовать `table` в 2016 это не хорошо, но в данной ситуации нужны были они. Когда вы перейдёте на сайт,в самом верху, есть черная пустота `body bgcolor=black`. Так вот как мне поднять табличку на самый верх через css? Или тут может быть проблема из-за php кода?

P.S.: с помощью css я немного поднял ее, но не совсем.

Comment: Хорошая попытка, но нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В классе `table` добавь:

```
margin-top: -36px;
```

Answer (score 0):

В инспекторе посмотрите верстку свою. У вас содержимое блока head почему то парсится в body - вот оно и дает воздух сверху.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]